# Simplest way to add a second html editor to the post/page admin?

Tags: page-template, editor, html

What's the simplest way to add a second HTML editor to the post/page admin and show the content in a template?

What I need is something like a custom field that supports html, but I don't need the options to name the field. And I don't need a visual editor like tinyMCE; just html will do.

What I'm thinking of is simply a small text-editor box that sits under the main visual/html editor and shows the resulting html in a template via `<?php if ( function_exists('my_extra_editor_content') ) ...` with the text/html in a styleable div.

Plugins like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/developers-custom-fields/ offer too much in terms of functions and choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Bill Erickson's [custom meta boxes](http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-metaboxes/)
or plugin like [Secondary HTML Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/secondary-html-content/) (probably the easiest solution)

Comment: Thanks, I tried both and both work well for different needs; Custom Meta Boxes and Fields for complex uses, and the Secodnary HTML Content for simple sites. But I now use CMB&F for everything.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this will help but any Custom Field input will support html. I use html there all the time for headings and custom text in posts and pages.

Answer (score 1):

For future travelers, the custom metaboxes are not a good idea for adding a second editor in pages. You should use [`wp_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/) function inside the `edit_page_form` action so the form can be displayed. (You should use `edit_form_advanced` action for custom post types)

Then you can use the `save_post` and get the value of the editor from `$_POST` object. Here's an example:

```
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'se24801_add_second_editor' );
function se24801_add_second_editor() {
    echo '<h2>Second Content </h2>'; 
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'second_content', true );
    wp_editor(
        $content,
        'second_content',
        array(
            'media_buttons' =>  true,
        )
    );    
} 

add_action( 'save_post', 'se24801_save_second_content' );
function se24801_save_second_content( $post_id ) {
    if(isset( $_POST['second_content'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'second_content', $_POST['second_content'] );
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a textarea in a meta box? Meta boxes are more user friendly.

About your requirement, it sounds like just a textarea will do. Please be aware that even full tinyMce based editors are possible using existing WordPress libraries.

Answer (score -2):

Update from 2020. This is now extremely easily achievable with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and using its provided function call `the_field('field_ref')` to insert in the page.

Comment: I point out in my original question that plugins offer **too much** functionality.