# Add a second rich text input to post editor, and make that content available in post template

Tags: posts, input

As per title, I want to add a second rich text editor (or whatever that's called now?) to the Post edit page, and then allow the content from that to be easily insertable inside any Post template page.

I've found a couple of references of how to do this, [this one particularly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24801/simplest-way-to-add-a-second-html-editor-to-the-post-page-admin) is the same question, but from a long time ago with now outdated answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going to leave the question, but I've just found that this is extremely easily achievable with Custom Fields if you don't want rich text, and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin if you do.

The fields are setup with ACF's UI in the WP control panel, and then inserted in the page with simply:

```
the_field('field_id');
```